# Why does browser give a 302 and Java gives me a 500 with the same data passed?

Tags: java

I am trying to scrape a URL using Java. Basically I reproduce everything that was sent using browser including all the headers and POST requests, referrer etc. Note that the POST request is unique for my request that it is not influenced by a login. So, a simple copy and paste from Firefox's Tamper Data's given POST request has proved useful for such kind of replication.

```
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.example.com");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty(/*OTHER HEADERS ALSO*/);
    urlParameters = "...";
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

[image: tamper data]

Now, the above image is that from Tamper Data (My browsers data) showing the 1st response code is 302 and then there is another request whose response code is 200. But, `responseCode` in my code always shows a 500 (should be 302). Is there something wrong that I am doing? The POST data(forms the `urlParameters` variable in the given code) is as follows (This was totally copied from Tamper Data and is unique for my request as same in other browsers also):-

```
__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTEyMDE3MzgzNDUPZBYCAgMPZBYKAgEPEA8WBh4ORGF0YVZhbHVlRmllbGQFB1Nlc3Npb24eDURhdGFUZXh0RmllbGQFB1Nlc3Npb24eC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZ2QQFQIACTIwMTUtMjAxNhUCAAkyMDE1LTIwMTYUKwMCZ2dkZAIDDxAPFgYfAAUHQ1N0cmVhbR8BBQdDU3RyZWFtHwJnZBAVAgAEQkNPTRUCAARCQ09NFCsDAmdnZGQCBQ8QDxYGHwAFBHllYXIfAQUEeWVhch8CZ2QQFQQAATEBMgEzFQQAATEBMgEzFCsDBGdnZ2cWAQIBZAIHDxAPFgYfAAUIU2VtZXN0ZXIfAQUIU2VtZXN0ZXIfAmdkEBUCAAdTZW0gLSBJFQIAB1NlbSAtIEkUKwMCZ2dkZAILDw9kFgIeB29uY2xpY2sFEXJldHVybiB2YWxpZGF0ZSgpZGR%2BP3WXZxkNSdwV329YkiOBBIA2DLMC6gJWNx4dA3oG5Q%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=18D1343D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAA2G%2FZz3h1Fxl4xXSSABzk8Pb%2BUXWva1oWT3WqhNzatWVhEoIdYgal8I9hPfCoT1Itb7%2F7%2FyZSxxhcd9q9F7xksY%2FSdZeiYB08giIx9FAbkawOhcMS1yLyZ52cUQpBBi9r5shpYmVHzGls1H3mvqZEXw%2BZkl20IpE0Nr6jkkTdSbTjxJdi%2BkoPCwQLNr0uqw0NPQS5HQgTWcg263rJ2nwCO5DBdXef%2BTfjQcyvts5G%2Bbf%2FsH0gjLf9q4vWrLQV0SZzu1qAVHBnj%2FrF82mykk7zwRtJ8FryYi9kZUwYQMnOtqn2%2B7o7zN0ZhgzU6s38KDRXw%3D&ddlSession=123456&ddlStream=xxx&ddlYear=xx&ddlSemester=xxx&txtRoll=987654&btnViewAttendance=xxxx
```

Comment: I don't think viewstate should be hardcoded.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard, but it is just the same for all requests made from different browsers.

Comment: can you please try same with postman, and give us the feedback?, sometimes its problem with querystring data we send from java, check on escapes and url encoding.

Comment: How about cookies (session)? If your browser sends them the server might be able to associate the view state with the session. But if your application doesn't then this might explain the 500.

Comment: @Thomas, now while tampering the data in Firefox, I removed the Cookies header using Tamper Data but the page loads normally. Thus, cookies do not play a role here

Comment: OK @Thomas I did a little more research. The thing is that, **in the browser,** when the first URL is loaded without the cookies, there is no effect and in its request, it gives a 302 status and also has a `Set-Cookie` header. Now if the second URL (i.e. the URL from the `Location` header of this response) is requested without the cookies, ***BAM!*** 500. What do I interpret from this?

Comment: The JavaDoc on `HttpUrlConnection#setInstanceFollowRedirects(...)` says: `The default value comes from followRedirects, which defaults to true.` Thus most probably your connection will follow the redirect but won't use the cookie that is returned.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `URLConnection` instead of a library like Apache's HttpClient?

Comment: Did you try to set the Content-Type explicitly?